# Migrate a MongoDB cluster to another account

Tags: mongodb

I have been developing my application using a MongoDB (M0) cluster which is a free cluster. Is it possible to migrate that existing cluster to another MongoDB account ?

Answer (score 0):

Dump all databases and restore them in the other cluster.